# "Above your pay grade" or "beyond your pay grade"

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

Which is correct: *above your pay grade* or *beyond your pay grade*? If both are alright, which is better?

Comment: I think this is General Reference. Googling ["beyond my pay grade"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22beyond+my+pay+grade%22&oq=%22beyond+my+pay+grade%22&aqs=chrome.0.57.5791186&sugexp=chrome,mod=18&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) gets 281,000 hits, whereas ["above my pay grade"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22above+my+pay+grade%22&oq=%22above+my+pay+grade%22&aqs=chrome.0.57j60j62l3.6489&sugexp=chrome,mod=18&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) gets 2,270,000 hits (the top one being a Wikipedia article on the idiomatic usage).

Comment: I think it is **above**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the USA, it's also usually *above*. *Beyond* would suggest that it's not possible for you to ever reach that pay grade because you haven't got the required education for the job, for example.

Answer (score 2):

In the UK, it's usually *above*.

Comment: Someone disagree?

Answer (score 2):

Take a few extra hours or a freelance job and you can get the thing that is *above*. Despair that you totally can't afford it if it's *beyond*.